# Printable characters in Symbian

Tags: c++, symbian

Normalley, one could use the isprint(int) function to determine if a character
is printable or not. This function is included in the estlib.lib in Symbian. Unfortunately,
the capabilities do not allow me to link against this library. Therefore, I wondering
if anybody knows an alternative way to figure out wether a character is printable or not.

Thanks
Philipp

Comment: TCB?? please confirm you understand what you are doing with the TCB capability. I suspect not being able to link to estlib is only the first of many problems this will cause.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TChar::IsPrint`](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/TCharClass.html#%3a%3aTChar%3a%3aIsPrint%28%29const).

(Platform security capabilities do not prevent you from linking with `estlib` so in that sense you could also use `isprint`.)

Comment: Thanks for that. If I try to link with  estlib I get the following: ERROR: *PlatSec* ERROR - Capability check failed. Can't load \bin\TechView\epoc32\release\armv6\udeb\filesystem.fsy because it links to estlib{000a0000}[10003b0b].dll
which has the following capabilities missing: TCB. So in my case I cant use estlib.

Comment: Ah, you're working with TCB which explains a lot. estlib and many other libraries are really for user-mode code, not TCB :)